# Blender: object disappears upon transform (grab, scale, rotate...)

Tags: object, blender

In Blender 2.8 beta, in edit mode, the object I want to transform or move or do anything to it at all disappears while I transform it, so I can't be precise about the transformation. How do I keep it on sight so I can see exactly how it is being transformed? Isn't it unseemly to have to switch to object mode?

Answer (score 1):

That is because transform pivot point is set to 3d cursor. set it to median point. i had the same problem and this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using beta, I think this is a bug.

If you want to, you may report it, but as far I'm aware you can only report bugs on official releases.

To fix the problem, is it possible for you to download and switch to a stable version?

Comment: It is, but the bug is not happening anymore!